# Android Using Fragments?

Tags: android

I am developing application which uses fragments?Here is my problem.

```
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mocksample/com.mocksample.MockProject}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.mocksample.MockProject.onCreate(MockProject.java:11)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     ... 11 more
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mocksample-2.apk]
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-23 15:58:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

Here is my code...

```
public class MockProject extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

xml code..

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.mocksample.Suggestion" />
```

suggestion class.

```
public class Suggestion extends Fragment {
}
```

Comment: so your main.xml contains the fragment?

Comment: also, your Suggestion fragment, is it blank? or you haven't included it in your post?

Comment: sry for delay,i have some cod ei suggestion also just i have not pasted it..

Comment: Could you precise which android api is targeted? It's important to know that to answer since you will have to use the android support package for api lower than android-11 (by memory).

Comment: sure  i have targted 4.0 and i have removed sdk version in manfiestfile..

Comment: Ok, i delete my OT answer then

Comment: when i have debugged it causing the exception at this line..setContentView(R.layout.main); i have used android supportpackage...

Comment: means i am thinking exception is caused in xml file...

Comment: what SDK of the device where do you deploy your app?

Comment: in emulator...i have targted of , api level 8 version..

Comment: and you're not using compatibility library?

Comment: You can't deploy fragments in preHoneyComb devices without Compatibility Package. Basically, the device doesn't understand the fragments since they were introduced later, in API level 11. Try deploying the app in emulator with API level 14.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5269/discussion-between-nikhilreddy-gujjula-and-pdt)

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are using compatability package.. and also instead of class in fragment tag.. use `android:name`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.mocksample.Suggestion" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Activity to FragmentActivity.

```
public class MockProject extends FragmentActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: also make sure onCreateView() in your Suggestion class returning view properly

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to re add the latest compatibility library from eclipse Android menu and then continue to the next steps.

Use a Fragment activity such as the one mentioned by Santhosh Shettigar

```
public class MockProject extends FragmentActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And also make sure that in the layoyut main.xml you have the fragment declared as:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.mocksample.Suggestion" />
```

Make sure that in your custom fragment you implement the following method

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
```

For additional details you can also check Google docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).